# Google Map API key expires

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, ionic-framework

I have generated a `Google Map API` Key using Google console and currently that has 'None' restriction. It works fine and I am able to consume `Google Places API` without any problem. I am using `Ionic` framework and my application is purely based on HTML and AngularJS (JavaScript).

Now as my key works as expected for some duration, it stops working all of a sudden after sometime. Google service returns 'UNKNOWN ERROR' as response for all calls. To resolve this I need to generate another key and without code changes everything works fine. I have used URL `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDgM6rXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXTA68vY5g&callback=&libraries=places` and pasted it in browser and copied the content of the generated JavaScript in a file and referring it locally. Also FYI, I don't have any server side code with me.

Now I have precisely 2 questions.

1. Do I need to change my `Google API key` every week to keep it active? Or once the restriction is set to 'Android' or 'HTTPS' then the key will work as long as I want?
2. If I publish my app in Android store is it safe to place the Google API Key in app files (JavaScript or HTML)? Is there a better way of doing it? Google best practices says we should keep it outside root, but then how should I do it?

Answer (score 2):

You might not have billing enabled on your project.

Without billing enabled you only get 1,000 free requests per 24 hour period (calculated as the sum of client-side and server-side requests). 
After you enable billing you get up to [150,000 requests per 24 hour period free of charge](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/usage#usage_limits).

It might be slightly confusing that JS API Places library usage counts against the Places API limit, but that is the case:  the daily usage is calculated as the [sum of client-side and server-side requests combined](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#quotas).

Comment: Re: 1 seems you might want to create a bug report under: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry sharing the project id of your project (visible in the URL of the developer console) https://console.developers.google.com/apis/dashboard?project=api-project-404198226339 (here api-project-404198226339) 

2. for now there is no better way if you are not using the native SDK

Comment: Thanks. I have raised a bug as suggested by you. Regarding 2nd, I just hope it is safe to do what I am doing (or hacking may incur charges if some body using my key). I also guess there would be many who use Ionic (angular) with pure HTML to develop apps.

Comment: Can you link the issue you created? Re: 2 - it is not 100% safe  - you should check your usage from time to time. issue is you cannot really set a referer authorization when you use local files on mobiles.